# Dosbox shut down while create text file

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, dosbox

Why after i create the file my dosbox will shut down automatically?? any problem of my code?

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg1    db      10, 13, 10, 13, "Please select an item:",0Dh,0Ah,0Dh,0Ah,09h
        db      "1- Create File",0Dh,0Ah,09h
        db      "2- show data",0Dh,0Ah,09h      
        db      "3- Exit",0Dh,0Ah,09h
        db      "Enter item number: " 
        db      '$'   
msg2    db      10,13,"Success Create$"
file    db      "test.txt"
handle  dw      ?
buffer  dw      10 dup (?)

.code
main proc 
    mov   ax,@data
    mov   ds,ax

ShowMenu:       
    lea     dx, msg1  
    mov     ah, 09h 
    int     21h     

    mov     ah, 01h ;get choice
    int     21h        

    cmp     al, "1"
    je      CreateFile
    cmp     al, "2"
    je      ShowData
    cmp     al, "3"
    jmp     Quit
    jl      ShowMenu

Quit: 
   mov   ah,4ch
   int   21h   

CreateFile:
mov ah,3ch ;create file
mov cx,0
lea dx,file;set file name
int 21h

lea dx,msg2
int 21h
jmp ShowMenu

ShowData:
mov ah,3dh ;open file
mov al,0   ;open as read only
lea dx,file
int 21h
mov handle,ax

;read one char
mov ah,3fh   ;service to read file
mov bx,handle
mov cx,1        ;how many byte to read
mov dx,buffer   ;where to store
int 21h

;close file
mov ah,3eh
mov bx,handle
int 21h

jmp ShowMenu


main endp
 end main
```

create a text file

Comment: `jmp Quit` should be `je Quit`?

Comment: i have tried but my doxbox will still close

Comment: You aren't setting ah before trying to show "Success Create$".  This means that whatever the return value is from the `CREAT` call is what it's going to use as the function number.  Who knows what that might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of not setting the function code 09h before displaying the success message ([comment by David Wohlferd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880686/dosbox-shut-down-while-create-text-file#comment94609100_53880686)) would normally just close your program but **not** the DOSBox emulator.
The handle that you get from creating a file would ordinarily leave `AH=0` and that would subsequently invoke a DOS termination function.[Terminate program](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2551.htm)

---

> ```
> file    db      "test.txt"
> handle  dw      ?
> ```

A further problem in your program is that you forgot to zero-terminate the filespec:

```
 file    db      "test.txt", 0
```

A garbage filespec could potentially make DOSBox shutdown!

Because the handle variable is defined with ? (uninitialized memory) you could be unlucky that the following byte does not happen to be a zero.